# Installing my plug-in in Eclipse destroys the Maven Project Wizard

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

I`m developing my own editor plug-in in Eclipse. After I installed it into a new, freshly downloaded Eclipse version the Maven Project Wizard of Eclipse encounters an error like this: [image]

The error message is: `Problem Opening Wizard. The selected wizard could not be started.
Plug-in org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.MavenProjectWizard.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui (236).`

The m2e package was preinstalled in the target Eclipse. The wizard only breaks after I install my plug-in, and works before.

This is the `Manifest.MF`of my plugin listing all dependencies:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Language Editor Core
Bundle-SymbolicName: language-editor-core;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.jface.text;bundle-version="3.11.2",
 org.eclipse.ui.editors;bundle-version="3.10.1",
 org.eclipse.ui.views;bundle-version="3.8.102",
 org.eclipse.ui.console;bundle-version="3.6.201",
 org.eclipse.jdt.core;bundle-version="3.12.3",
 org.eclipse.ui.ide;bundle-version="3.12.3",
 org.eclipse.ui;bundle-version="3.108.1",
 org.eclipse.jdt.ui;bundle-version="3.12.2",
 org.eclipse.core.runtime;bundle-version="3.12.0",
 org.eclipse.core.resources;bundle-version="3.11.1",
 language.editor.bundle,
 org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui;bundle-version="1.7.0"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Export-Package: de.se_rwth.langeditor.global,
 de.se_rwth.langeditor.injection,
 de.se_rwth.langeditor.language;uses:="org.antlr.v4.runtime,org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree,com.google.common.collect",
 de.se_rwth.langeditor.modelpath,
 de.se_rwth.langeditor.modelstates,
 de.se_rwth.langeditor.texteditor,
 de.se_rwth.langeditor.texteditor.commands,
 de.se_rwth.langeditor.texteditor.contentassist,
 de.se_rwth.langeditor.texteditor.errorhighlighting,
 de.se_rwth.langeditor.texteditor.hyperlinks,
 de.se_rwth.langeditor.texteditor.outline,
 de.se_rwth.langeditor.texteditor.syntaxhighlighting,
 de.se_rwth.langeditor.util,
 de.se_rwth.langeditor.util.antlr,
 de.se_rwth.langeditor.util.prefuse
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Import-Package: org.junit
```

Any thoughts how to fix it?
EDIT: After looking into the `.log` file in the workspace it turns out that the error is caused by this: `.Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext does not implement the requested interface org.slf4j.ILoggerFactory`

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Please past text of error message cause many people can't access the images...

Comment: Added the text of the error message

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is more details about the error.

Comment: I added further information to the error found in the `.log` file